# Reflash Windows 8 from HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-8, boot, dell-inspiron

I just got a new Dell Inspiron 14z. Windows 8 is installed in the 500GB HDD partition and apparently there is nothing in the 32GB SSD partition. I want Windows to boot from the SSD partition. Booting time is supposed to improve if the OS boots from the SSD. SHow do I go about it?

Comment: You didn't indicate what sort of data usage you have.  32GB does not leave a great deal of room for your applications and personal data.  Windows 8 alone will take 50-60% of your storage space.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. You could always check what SSD is build in and buy the exact same one (32gb isn't that expensive) and put them into a RAID 0. More Space and faster. The only downfall is when one of the two fail your system won't boot and probably lose most of your Data. But it rarely happens. I have two SSDs in RAID 0 running for about one and a half years without any problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care reinstalling Windows, do that. Purge both drives and install it onto the SSD.

If there is already data on the system partition you want to keep, you can try to shrink the partition size of the system to fit the SSD, then boot from a live linux and copy over the the system partition from HDD to SSD using the linux dd command.

On reboot, press F12 (or whatever your boot menu key is) and choose the SSD as boot device.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way without reinstalling Windows 8 again is to Clone your 500gb HDD to the SSD. You can do that with this: [XClone](http://www.xxclone.com/index.htm)

But before you do that backup your DATA somewhere. If you want another program google a bit and i'm sure youl find som other free software. :)

After that reboot into your bios and choose your SSD to boot from.